# Snackbar action gets null pointer after moving to another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-snackbar, snackbar

Fragment A invokes a snackbar with an action button. When user clicks action, it starts new activity with intent.
It's working fine. However, if the user moves to Fragment B while snackbar keeps appearing, then press action button, now it doesn't start new activity but crash.

[image]

How can I prevent crashing in this situation and make intent workable?
here is my code.
fragment A

```
binding.theButton.setOnClickListener {

    val proSnack = Snackbar.make(view!!, activity!!.getString(R.string.this_is_pro_function), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
    proSnack.setAction(R.string.check, View.OnClickListener {
        activity!!.startActivity(Intent(activity, ProActivity::class.java))
    })
    proSnack.show()

    }
}

binding.backText.setOnClickListener{
    activity?.supportFragmentManager?.popBackStackImmediate()
}
```

Comment: Ideally you should dismiss the SnackBar when moving to next fragment . if u need show it in next fragment also then show a new one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 activity!!.startActivity(Intent(activity, ProActivity::class.java))
```

The problem is here. You can check **activity**. It is null. Using **!!** is a bad practice. You can change it to

```
activity?.startActivity(Intent(activity, ProActivity::class.java))
```

But the activity is null. It does not open a new activity

Comment: You are right. Not crashing now. Thank you for your advice.